# Credit card pending transaction

Tags: credit-card

Apple sent a replacement device (9/2) and placed a $547.16 pending debit on a credit card to ensure that return the defective device.  Today (9/8) Apple was gracious and accelerated the return process for me, however, the credit card company shows Apple's credit as debit.

CLARIFICATION: A conference call between me, Apple and the credit card company accelerated the return process.

[Link to transaction screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8i24.jpg)

Do I need to be concerned?  I feel concerned / uneasy.

Shouldn't today's transaction show up as credit on the pending charges?

Comment: See how it plays out. Contact them if needed. No need to worry, they will make it right if it was a mistake

Answer (score 4):

Wait until they either move to a real charge, or disappear.

Typically, entries under 'pending' disappear after a number of days; they do not get explicitly 'removed' by the vendor.
There is nothing Apple can do to make them disappear, only wait. Once (and *if*) they become real charges, you should act.

Comment: +1 - I removed the word 'probably' because the second line is right, it falls off when the real charge doesn't hit. This is also a reason why living with debit cards (I'm referencing the anti-CC people here) exclusively can be an issue, a $600 hold on your money, and the need to wait for it to pass. Hopefully OP didn't need to use this piece of his credit line these few days.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer  good insight comment.  This is a credit card not a debit card.

Comment: @gatorback - agreed. For OP, this is a non-issue. For debit people, this can ruin their day. My comment is a tangent, the "hold" process is the same.

Comment: My buddy has had the nightmare of his entire bank account frozen because of the purchase of a cell phone CASE ($30) for his teenager.  This is another reason why my CC is NOT from my bank and I do not permit automatic pull payments from the bank to the CC.  IMHO Best to separate these functions with different organizations so that computer fraud algorithms affect only CC function and not banking.

Answer (score 1):

Is the idea here supposed to be that you are getting a replacement whatever gadget for free, provided that you return the old, defective one? So that when everything is done the net charge on your card should be zero? If so, yes, I would be concerned. It looks like Apple is billing you for the $547. I would call them and get this straightened out.

Comment: Your understanding of the situation is correct.  Apple acknowledged that device was returned in the conference call